# How to set file name and extension to the original when inserting a file with full url or URI in CollectionFS?

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

Model code:

```
ProfileImage = new FS.Collection('profileImage', {
  stores: [
    new FS.Store.FileSystem('profile-image')
  ],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 524288,
    allow: {
      extensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'],
      contentTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
    }
  }
});
```

Insertion code:

```
ProfileImage.insert('http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.services.facebook.id + '/picture/?type=large', function(error, imageObj) {
  console.log(imageObj);
});
```

with that code I get a file name like this: **profileImage-iiGE2ouSifuu3iLjq-undefined** .

the name is undefined and without extension at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (copied from a project of mine. this works):

```
//this is the event for when you select an image
'change .yourfileinput': function (event, template) {
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
            var yourFile = new FS.File(file);
            Images.insert(yourFile, function (err, fileObj) {
                var fileUrl = '/cfs/files/profile-image/'+fileObj._id;
                Session.set('fileUrl', fileUrl);
        });    
    });
},

//form submit event
"submit .your-form-class": function (event) {
    var whichUser = Meteor.userId() //or you could just write this inside the method call instead of adding a variable
    var profilePicture = Session.get('fileUrl');
    Meteor.call("yourMethod", whichUser, profilePicture);
}
```

Of course, you need to play on it/customise to your needs. ^ is for default file path of cfs:filesystem.

I switched to gridfs though and I highly recommend it.

Edit your question with all your code if it doesn't work and we'll find a solution. File upload was the biggest problem I encountered along the way.

Comment: sorry, it looks you didn't understand my question well.
I'm using full url to insert the image not an input. I'll edit my code to put a url instead of the variable.

Comment: to be able to have the image as /imagename.jpg, you need to have your own custom path. I can also give an example of that BUT the profileImage-iiGE2ouSifuu3iLjq-undefined is because you miss something when you define the url. Let me know if your path is custom or default. it could also be console.log(imageObj+imageObj._id);. I need to see your full code though

Comment: this is my full code and the url I pass is like this: `'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.services.facebook.id + '/picture/?type=large'`. yes, the path is default.

Comment: @RaeefRefai oh, do you want to save the images from FB login? Then why don't you use an onCreated for when the user signs up? I can write that one if you want. Much easier solution + user's image changes in your app if they change their profile picture on FB

Comment: I know that, but I'm new to Meteor and CollectionFS and need that for other purposes and this is just to learn how to do it. The problem now is that when I insert in CollectionFS with full url or URI then the file is being saved with undefined name and without extension at all.

Comment: @RaeefRefai I think your mistake is where you define your file url. could you upload your project to github or somewhere else so that I can check and see whats going on?

Comment: mmm, I've just tried a direct image url, and it works well.. but what about URI? when I use ng-img-crop for example, I get undefined name and without extension.